# Use Fancybox for all possible Urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I want fanybox to open all possible media content links on the page.

Let's say I have three anchor links on the page,

**Html**

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Google (Just a link to google)</a>
<a href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">Image 1</a>
<a href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg">Image 2</a>
```

The first one is just a link to google (not an image) and the others are image links (jpg), would be vimeo, youtube or any other content link that fancybox can show up.

**Javascript**

```
// Fancybox initializing
$("a")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox();

/*
   When I try to trigger first link of gallery, 
   it doesn't open the gallery, because it's not a media content 
   that fancybox can open.
   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Py2RA/1599/
*/
$("button").click(function() {
    $("a").eq(0).trigger("click");
});

/*
   But when I trigger second or third one gallery shows up.
   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Py2RA/1600/
*/
$("button").click(function() {
    $("a").eq(1).trigger("click");
});
```

### Problem:

Actually content is dynamic, let's say I have fifty links on the page and I have no idea about which one is just a link to another page, a youtube link, an image link, a vimeo link or something else.

I just want fancybox the open gallery with the possible ones or let me know which link it can show up.

[Demo - 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Py2RA/1599/)

[Demo - 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Py2RA/1600/)

Comment: are you able to hard-code more html or you want the script to do everything for you? ... BTW, you won't ever open google in fancybox (or any other lightbox) because as same as many other sites, it can't be contained in an iframe

Comment: I know, I can't open google in fancybox, just want fancybox to ignore google link and show up the next one. I have found a solution by using  $.fancybox.helper.media to achive this problem. I will put it here when I have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I achieve the problem,

```
//this part of code check if the link can be shown in fancybox and set fancybox-group data attribute.
$("a").each(function() {
    var url   = this.href || '',
        mediaDefaults = $.fancybox.helpers.media.defaults,
        type  = false,
        what,
        item,
        rez,
        params;
    if ($.fancybox.isImage(url) || $.fancybox.isSWF(url)) {
        $(this).attr("data-fancybox-group", "fancyboxlinks");
    } else {
        for (what in mediaDefaults) {
            if (mediaDefaults.hasOwnProperty(what)) {
                item = mediaDefaults[what];
                rez  = url.match(item.matcher);

                if (rez) {
                    $(this).attr("data-fancybox-group", "fancyboxlinks");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

// Now here you can initialize fancybox here
// Selector just select the link that can be used for fancybox.
$("a[data-fancybox-group]").fancybox();

$("button").click(function() {
    $("a[data-fancybox-group]").eq(0).trigger("click");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Py2RA/1609/)

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("a").gt(0).trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: If you mean `$("a:gt(0)").trigger("click")` or `$("a").get(0)` I think you didn't get my question.

Comment: I guess I didn't get your question. And, yes, I meant `a:gt(0)`